# Xcode configuration options for dependancies

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an Xcode project with several static library dependancies set up in the Target's build options.

This means everytime I build the project, the dependancies also get built.

My question is, which configuration is chosen for the dependancies when they are built?

E.g. In my project, I select 'App Store' as the configuration to build against.  In the Build Results tab, I can see that Xcode is building my dependancies with the 'App Store' configuration as well.  The issue is that those dependancies do not have an 'App Store' configuration set up.

What then, is the config it is using?

Comment: Are your dependencies additional targets within the main project or are they subprojects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there isn't a configuration with a matching name, it uses the default configuration for that project (see the bottom of the Configurations tab in the project settings window). For more details, see the [Xcode docs on configurations](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/400-Build_Configurations/build_configs.html).

You can verify that by looking at the build logs, and seeing what configuration is listed when it gets to building those target.